# Cannot throw an Error in React hook set function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got the following code in a custom react hook that could possibly raise an error based on the previous state data.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

const handleSomething = () => {
  setData((oldData) => {
    if (/* some condition based on oldData */) {
      throw new Error('Bad');
    }
    // Other code
    return newData;
  });
}
```

But when I do something like the following:

```
try {
  handleSomething()
} catch (err) {
  console.log('There was an error');
}
```

My `catch` block isn't entered and the error still gets raised. From my guess it seems like React is raising the error up and then crashing the up instead of allowing me to do it. How could I avoid something like this?

Comment: so you're saying the Error is being thrown, and the catch block is never getting entered?

Comment: Well state updates are asynchronous, and you can't catch errors from async stuff in synchronous code, cos the synchronous stuff has already been popped from the stack by the time the async stuff is executed. It's not a React thing, it's just how Javascript works. You'll have to reorganise how you check for, raise and handle the error.

Comment: Totally makes sense, Didn't even think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jayce444 said, `setData` would be asynchronous so it cannot be caught. No basic way around it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in React >= version 16: look at the lifecycle methods: componentDidCatch() & static getDerivedStateFromError()...